# Efficiently storing a set of integer sequences in python

Tags: python, data-structures, integer, sequence

I have a large set of integer sequences, small sample below:

```
1
2
1
1 2
1 3 2
4
1 3 2
...
```

Simply storing them as a list of tuples gives me memory errors, so I am looking for a better datastructure that can hold them (or the equivalent information). The order among the sequences is not important (i.e. the sequences do not have an id) but the order *within* each sequence needs to be preserved.

Any idea on how to do this efficiently? I am considering a nested dictionary; for the example above would then look like this:

```
{1: {2: {-1: 1}, 
     3: {2: {-1: 2}, -1: 0}, 
    -1: 2}, 
 2: {-1: 1}, 
 4: {-1: 1}}
```

The "leaf" values (given by key -1) are the counts of the respective sequences. Of course, this does not take advantage of the fact that all keys are integers.

Roughly speaking, I am looking to manage about a billion sequences, of average length 3, with a large amount of redundancy. The number of distinct integers is around one million. Any good ideas/existing libraries?

**EDIT** :

It should be efficient to build "subsets" of the datastructure, as follows. Given an integer `x`, get only the sequences that contain `x`. For example, if `x=2`, then we would build from the initial datastructure the following subset:

```
{1: {2: {-1: 1}, 
     3: {2: {-1: 2}, -1: 0}, 
    -1: 0}, 
 2: {-1: 1}}
```

If possible, I would also like to be able to build a subset as follows. I specify a pair of integers `(x,y)`, and the corresponding subset is the set of sequences where both `x` and `y` occur, and the first `x` occurs before the first `y`. For example, for `(x,y)=(1,2)` we would get

```
{1: {2: {-1: 1}, 
     3: {2: {-1: 2}, -1: 0}, 
    -1: 0}}
```

I don't have explicit O(log n) requirements, in the end it should just run as fast as possible :) Unfortunately I can not provide an actual data sample, as it is not mine to share.

Comment: Is this something you need in your memory throughout the codes execution? Or can you store it into a file/database?

Comment: How many distinct entire sequences are we talking? Most? Or is the 1 billion number all distinct sequences?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson OP already wrote " Roughly speaking, I am looking to manage about a billion sequences, of average length 3, with a large amount of redundancy. The number of distinct integers is around one million. Any good ideas/existing libraries? "

Comment: @InbarRose Yes, but there are multiple integers per sequence. He says "large amount of redundancy", but that is not very specific.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from your sample list to your sample dict?   Is it the same example or am I missing something?

Comment: @InbarRose : I am very much hoping to get this in memory, yes.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : the number of distinct sequences is hard to say, perhaps 100 million.

Comment: @mitchus you will need to provide a small sample set, which includes the data structure of the items... and how you want to be able to access then.. possibly a small sample of your code to see how it shall be used.. to better determine the best method of structuring your data. - It would also help to know where this data is coming from? Is it obtained while running? Or is it always the same?

Comment: @Joop :  Yes, it is the same example. The dict is actually a trie, as pointed out by Useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the amount of redundancy, you may get good compression using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which collapses all common prefixes.

It looks like you're aiming in that direction with your nested dictionary structure, but a hash map isn't necessarily the most space-efficient store for this (you don't mention any requirement for lookup performance).

For example, consider storing it as nested lists, with a 1-tuple to distinguish the leaf value (although we can probably come up with something cleaner):

```
trie = [ [1, (2,),
             [2, (1,)],
             [3, [2, (2,)]],
         [2, (1,)],
         [4, (1,)]
       ]
```

With average length 3, this should be pretty shallow, and hopefully there is less slack at each level using a list instead of a dictionary.

Note if some branches are long and bare, you can compress redundant depth at the cost of code complexity. Consider the subtree

```
[1, [2, [3, ... [n, (1,)]...]]]
```

could be coded instead as

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., n, (1,)]
```

so long as you distinguish between flat sequences and siblings (here, a *leaf* is always a 1-tuple, a *subtree* is always a list, and anything else is the next element in a flat sequence).

---

The new subset requirement is more complex. I can think of some possible approaches:

1. naive/brute-force search: depending again on your access pattern, you could return a generator instead of an eager full-depth copy of the matching subtrees (sub-tries)
2. store a bloom filter at the top of each subtree, indicating the values found within.
   Your search works the same as (1), except you can quickly skip subtrees that cannot match.

   - Each level's filter is just a logical OR of the filters in its children
3. if you need to do the lookup quickly, you could a reverse lookup. For example this could be a set of each sequence containing a key (so you'd have one million keys). After taking the union of the sequences containing *x* and those containing *y*, you'd need to iterate over the results to see which had *x* and *y* in the right order.

   The difficulty with this scheme is *representing* each sequence. You either need a link to the leaf node in your Trie (and be able somehow to iterate from leaf to root), or you need a separate flat copy of each sequence, which seems wasteful

Comment: Indeed, looks like I was thinking of a trie, thanks for the link! Regarding lookup requirements, Inbar Rose also pointed out that I should mention how I would use the datastructure, so I am editing my question.

Comment: Did this get enough compression, then? I'd be interested to know how it worked out.

Comment: Yes, for storage it achieves strong improvements on my sequences. The datasets are compressed by factors 10 to 100.

Answer (score 1):

For as short sequences as average 3 integers, I can't see anything more efficient than encoding them as arrays with a reference count;

```
[
 (2, [1]),
 (1, [2]),
 (1, [1, 2]),
 (2, [1, 3, 2]),
 (1, [4])
]
```

Consider this; with the Trie as suggested, for each new subsequence, you'll need at least one new array and a tuple, which means 100M arrays and tuples, just like this version. Array storage also has a *maximum* of 100M arrays/tuples, while the Trie does not if subsequences diverge by multiple digits. The Trie shines with longer sequences where a lot of duplication is eliminated, but throwing in an extra array to save on average <2 integers is not enough to give a distinct advantage.

You could even remove the tuple by adding the refcount as a first element in the array and save even more memory. As a secondary benefit, can you see any simpler way to iterate a sequence than iterating an array?

As for space optimized arrays, you could look at the [array module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).